# Divs on top of each other css

Tags: css

I want to make the div 1 on top of the div 2, but this doesn't work

```
    .div1, div2 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
.div1{

  left:-50px;

  position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
.div2{
  left:-50px;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't here for *just you*. The whole point of people volunteering **free expert-level consultations** to people like you is that we're creating a resource for **everyone**. If you go and delete your question so that the answers can't help anyone else, you destroy that resource. Do not delete your answered questions like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the blue box on top you have to give it a higher z-index value. Right now it is lower.

That doesn't really matter though because you have them both floated and margined left so that they don't actually overlap.

Try giving the red box `margin-left: -200px` and give the blue box `z-index: 10`.

Answer (score 1):

If your blue box appears first in the HTML, then change bluebox's left to px and redbox's left to -204px.  If the red box appears first in the HTML, then change redbox's left to 0px and bluebox's left to -204px.

(The extra 4 pixels is for the 2 px border on either side.)

Using Myles' JSFiddle, here is a demo of the position:relative solution: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkJL3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid negative `z-index` values,

try using `z-index:1` on `.bluebox` and `z-index:2` on `.redbox`

Here you go:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/wkJL3/5/)**

Clever blend of absolute positioning and z-index :)

Comment: I want them to be on top of each other, not next to

Comment: IE has a bug with `z-index: 0;` always start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the boxes aren't overlapping because they're floating next to each other, then you move them both to the left 100px.  Try only moving the red box to the left, then give the blue box a higher `z-index` if you want it to be on top.  The `z-index` is the stacking order, where elements with lower numbers appear below elements with higher numbers.  The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) has good information on this topic.

With some slight tweaking, this works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/ZGJXt/2/